# angularjs filter option to work also with non consecutive words

Tags: filter, angularjs

hello everybody I am following the tutorial with angularjs

I am following the official angularjs tutorial with phones.

I wish to know if there is any chance that the filter: query option could be done also trough not contiguos words in the ng-repeat clause

In the example:
Phone name : Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

Search Filter: Samsung Galaxy. Result--> is found
Search Filter: Samsung Tab. Result--> is not found

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:query | orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo:limit" class="ng-scope">
                <td>{{product.id}}</td>
                <td><img ng-src="{{product.ThumbPictureForIndexing}}" style="width:70px;"></td>
                <td>{{product.TitlePerIndexing}}</td>
                <td>{{product.sku}}</td>
                <td>{{product.Ean_Code}}</td>

            </tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not contiguos words". What kind of filter are you thinking about?

Comment: I added a bit of explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to write your own "predicate function" for that kind of filtering/searching.  See the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter).